# Image not stretching to the full size of div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stretch an image to the full size of it's div (column left) using the `object-fit` CSS property, however it doesn't seem to be working. Please see this https://codepen.io/bradscanvas/pen/XWWNqWp?editors=1000

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

  .form-wrapper {
    border
  }  
.row {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  align-items: center;
  }
  
.column {
  text-align: center;

}
  img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
  
 .left {
  width: 40%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.right {
  width: 60%;
  padding: 20px;
}
  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .left {
    display: none;
  }
    .right {
      width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="form-wrapper">
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left">
<img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0196/2898/2334/files/MU6.jpg?2930">
  </div>
  <div class="column right">
    <i class="fa fa-unlock fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h2> You're In </h2>
    <p> You deserve it. Unlock your welcome discount and be the first to know about leaked artwork & exclusive offers. </p>
    <h2> GET $20 NOW </h2>
<form class="omnisend-subscribe-form" style="padding-left: 5%; padding-right: 5%"><input type="text" class="omnisend-subscribe-input-email" placeholder="Email address" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #a0a0a0; font-size: 16px; padding: 6px; border: 1px solid #cfcfcf; margin-bottom: 5px; outline-width: 0px; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;" /> <input type="submit" value="I want my $20 off" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; display: block; color: #ffffff; font-size: 16px; padding: 8px; margin-top: 18px; background-color: #f47268; border-width: 0px; -webkit-border-radius: 0px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 0px; outline-width: 0px; cursor: pointer;" /></form>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

No result

Comment: The image in your example is exactly the same width as it's parent div, what is your problem?

Comment: It's working just fine? If you add this css `.left {
  width: 40%;
   border-right: 1px solid black;
}` you will notice the image is right up against the edge of the `column left`, maybe consider making your LHS column larger?

Comment: The image is already filled its parent div's full width. What else do you want to do?

Comment: @EGC try right click -> inspect element and point to the `div` in the code, it's nicer and quicker than adding the css yourself

Comment: I would like to stretch the image height and width to fill the entire left column disregarding for aspect ratio.

Comment: I am aware how to use devtools, thanks tho. I was hoping to make it more obvious to @bradwalls by showing him visually..

Comment: @bradwalls what is happening at the moment you are unhappy with? From what I can tell it is stretched both vertically & horizontally to the maximum dimensions of the `column left` div

Comment: If you decrease screen width below a certain dimension, the image will shrink vertically from top and bottom. I would like it to stretch

Comment: Have you tried setting the image as a background image in the LHS div? You can set them to fit the size etc, is all

Answer (score 0):

```
.left {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

not sure if this is what you're looking for?
Is the background image supposed to stretch the full width of the screen?

Comment: this change has no effect in OP's example whatsoever